# Please help me to calculate a Bordered Hessian

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I was trying to find a global minimum for the function $$(a + b) z + (a + c) y + (b + c) x $$ according to the following constraint: $$(xy + xz + yz)(ab + bc + ac)=1.$$ By lagrange multipliers I found $2$ as a critical point, but how  calculating the  Bordered Hessian?Please help me to calculate a  Bordered Hessian.

Comment: Note:  unless the hessian finds this problem uninteresting, I assume you are referring to a [Bordered Hessian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix#Bordered_Hessian)

Comment: thank's lulu for your coment

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz is your best friend!

Comment: Why are you asking the same question twice?